# i am getting data from database and query is executed successfully and could not extract the result by using group by id

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

How to do i get driver id and driver name separately?

```
String hql="select count(tx.driver.driverid),tx.driver.drivername from Transaction tx group by driver"; 
return   (List)hibernateTemplate.find(hql);
```

service:

```
List list=driverService.groupby();
Iterator it=list.iterator();

while(it.hasNext())
{

    Object obj=(Object)it.next();
    System.out.println(obj);

}
```

result :

```
[Ljava.lang.Object;@1e65f750
[Ljava.lang.Object;@36d591df
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Create a result class:

```
package my.package;

public class DriverResultClass{

   private Integer count;
   private String name;

   public DriverResultClass(Integer count, String name){
      // set fields
   }
}
```

**2)** Alter your query:

```
select new my.package.DriverResultClass(count(tx.driver.driverid),tx.driver.drivername) 
from Transaction tx 
group by tx.driver.drivername
```

**3)** Change list type:

```
(List<DriverResultClass>)hibernateTemplate.find(hql)
```

Hibernate will not automatically populate the POJO object and wont need to extract manually from a List of Object arrays.